# How would I test for when a key is released in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I would like to have a variable become true when I press a key, and become false when it is released. I have a function that sets the var to true when the key is pressed, but I need to have a function called when a key is released as well to reset the var to false.

Comment: You're looking for [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)...

Comment: Thank you lc, I did do some googling, but nothing came up like this. maybe I am not good at Google, but please do not assume that I did not try just because I suck at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input onkeydown="doX();" onkeyup="doY();" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">     
   var flag = false;   
   function doX(){
      flag = true;        
   }

   function doY(){
     flag = false;    
   }
</script>
```

Expl:

There are two important keyboard events can help here.

1. keydown (will be fired when a key is pressed)
2. keyup (will be fired when a key is released)

call the doX function on keydown event and call doY function on keyup event!!

Code # 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("test");
    var flag;       
    input.onkeydown = function(){
        flag = false;
    }

    input.onkeyup = function(){
        flag = true;
    }
</script>
```

As, you asked to identify 'SPACE BAR', I have added the code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("test");
    var flag;       
    input.onkeydown = function(e){
        var char = e.keyCode; //32 is for 'SPACE BAR'           
        flag = false;
    };

    input.onkeyup = function(e){
        var char = e.keyCode; //32 is for 'SPACE BAR'           
        flag = true;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You can get all keyboard events from here

http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events

Comment: Inline event handling is not a good practice, and simply dumping code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: It's a straight forward answer. You don't need much explanation here. The developer might not know the 'events'.

Comment: Straight forward for you maybe. If it was straight forward for the OP this question wouldn't exist. What's the harm in a simple explanation?

Comment: What is the alternative to inline event handling? also, the code is very helpful. I have enough info from this answer to go about my work, thanks to Raja csp, but I would like to know what I should be doing insted

Comment: @Rajacsp you're just a ray of sunshine now, aren't you? If it was a waste of time, why did you edit your answer?

Comment: @xlirate the better way to handle events is through javascript, not via HTML attributes. Grab the element: `document.getElementById("myElement")` and then assign a function to it's `onkeydown`/`onkeyup` properties

Comment: @SterlingArcher what would that code look like? right now I am making the html with .innerHTML, it would not be a stretch to just make js handle the events, but I do not know how

Comment: @Rajacsp, if I wanted flag to only care about the space bar, how would the code look?

Comment: @xlirate, please check my updated code above.

You can check "e.keyCode or e.charCode" which is 32 for "SPACE BAR"!

Comment: @Rajacsp I have one div that is holding all of my canvases, and the program that I am making will create numerous canvases at run time, only one of them will be the game that the user is playing, which object should I use in get element by ID? I was unable to make it work using the div

Comment: @xlirate, could you explain your situation more detailed? I think I am missing the connection here.

Comment: @Rajacsp There is one div that the entire game runs in. The game creates numorus canvases as it goes. One of them is the local player's game, others are menus and so forth. I tried     var blah = document.getElementById("divName"); and blah.onkeydown = function(e){/*stuff*/} but it would never execute the stuff, so I have gone back to the inline method for now.